# Unable to Use Join Me App

Tags: software-recommendation

We are over 20 developers who use Ubuntu OS very extensively.

We use [join.me](https://www.join.me/) - screen sharing app for our weekly meetings 
while providing the presenter role to the UBUNTU user the app fails 
can you please provide an alternative?

Best Regards

Ignatius Rajkumar

Comment: I dont know the joinme software-  but if possible try to start it from terminal and if it crashes - check if the terminal displays some error output. If so - add that to your post.

Comment: i'm not sure if it's exactly what you want, but [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/Main/Features) comes in my mind...

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Google Hangouts](https://hangouts.google.com/).

It doesn't need installation. It runs through browser. You just sign in with your google account and add others via their google accounts. You can make large conference video calls and there are lots of utilities you can use including screen sharing.